# Using Variables in my URL to Filter data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using 2 variables (varDept and varType) in my URL to filter my data. Something like training.php?varDept=optical&varType=morning. My tables looks like schedule includes session, trainer, type while contact_info includes trainer, department.

```
SELECT DISTINCT schedule.Session
FROM schedule LEFT JOIN contact_info ON schedule.Trainer=contact_info.Trainer
WHERE contact_info.Department LIKE varDept AND schedule.Session LIKE varType
ORDER BY schedule.Session
```

Everything is working fine but occasionally I have some records that do not have a Department (VarDept) so the URL looks like training.php?varDept=&varType=morning. I would like to show the records that might not have a varDept but still have a Session, Trainer, Type. Currently it shows all records with training.php?varDept=&varType=morning. My varDept currently has a default value of % for $_GET['Dept'].

Comment: Can you detect in php that it is blank?

Comment: huh? care to elaborate.

Comment: Nice story, but I fail to see what your question or problem description is. What is it you are trying to solve, and where do you need our help? PS, is `%` an intentional default? You know this is an SQL wildcard, right?

Comment: I am using the page to load all by default, hence the %. I use the page secondarily from a dynamic link that feeds the variables.

Comment: Change 'WHERE' to 'AND'. Change 'AND' to 'WHERE'

Answer (score 2):

So check for varDept blank and omit that in the WHERE clause.
Something like this:

```
$dept = $_GET["varDept"]

$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT schedule.Session ";
$qry .= "FROM schedule LEFT JOIN contact_info ON ";
$qry .= "schedule.Trainer=contact_info.Trainer ";
$qry .= "WHERE schedule.Session LIKE varType ";
if( strlen($dept) )
    $qry .= " AND contact_info.Department LIKE $dept";

$qry .= "ORDER BY schedule.Session";
```

Comment: Replace ```strlen``` with ```empty```, because the function is not multi-byte and might generate an error in some cases. Other than that, this approach should solve the problem. P.S. A note to the author - I do hope you sanitize these GET variables :)

Comment: Currently I am not sanitizing. Just reading the variable. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: @user3258571 Fix? Sanitizing is another topic of discussion, but the least things you can do is to start using prepared statements, and strip any unwanted html or other dangerous input that the attacker could potentially submit. Try Googling "PHP PDO", "PHP strip_tags", "PHP xss", etc - there is tones of information on the topic, you will definitely find your answers. I believe your original question is solved and you should probably accept Mike's answer. :)